# Show that $ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx \geqslant 0 $ when $ h(x) \geqslant 0 $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I have the following simple question but I am a bit confused and would appreciate some help.

Note: I denote $ P_n $ as the partition of the interval $ [a,b] $ and $ m_i $ as the least upper bound of $ f(x) $ over the sub-intervals $ [x_{i-1}, x_i] $.

If the function $ f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R} $ is bounded, Riemann integrable and satisfies $ f(x) \geqslant 0 $ for all $ x \in [a, b] $, show that $ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx \geqslant 0 $.

I understand that since $ f(x) \geqslant 0 $ for all $ x \in [a, b] $, means that the value of the greatest lower bounds, $ m_i $, are all greater than or equal to zero. And so the lower integral of $ f(x) $ (i.e., $ L(P_n,f) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) $) will be greater than or equal to 0 if $ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1}) \geqslant 0 $.

If I can say that $ L(P_n,f) \geqslant 0 $ then it's easy to show $ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx \geqslant 0 $, this is what I am interested in showing.

But given only the information in the question, how can we ensure that it's true that $ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1}) \geqslant 0 $?

For example, if we are told that $ f(x) $ is increasing, then I have no problem.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't that part of the definition of the integral?

Comment: The points $x_i$ have nothing to do with $f$. You take a partition of the interval, $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n=b$. So by definition, $x_i$ is larger than $x_{i-1}$.

Comment: But isn't it always true that $x_{i-1} < x_i$?

Comment: I am stupid and confused myself, thanks guys.

Comment: @Mark You should post this as an answer since it answers the question